# MATLAB : tracking state change in imufilter object

Tags: c++, matlab

I am creating a function in MATLAB that I want to export as a c++ library. The function takes in accelerometer and gyroscope data, and calculates orientation via [imufilter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fusion/ref/imufilter-system-object.html). Here is how it works:

```matlab
% when 10 samples come in, call below function
function [orientation] = runtime_get_orientation(accelerometer, gyro)
    FUSE = imufilter('SampleRate', 50, 'AccelerometerNoise', 0.002, ...
           'LinearAccelerationNoise', 0.003, ...
           'GyroscopeNoise', 0.444, 'GyroscopeDriftNoise', 0.445);
    [orientation,~] = FUSE(accelerometer, gyro);
end
```

Note: I am creating a realtime system which will call this function over time. Ex: 10 samples come in, and then I call this function. 10 more come in, and I call it again.

The problem I see is that the FUSE object state is re-set every time I make a call to the function. Meaning, the matrix that retain the error state over time and adjust to it, are wiped. If I pass the FUSE object to the function, as demonstrated below, the state is kept and I can view orientation that makes sense.

```matlab
% define FUSE object outside of the function
FUSE = imufilter('SampleRate', 50, 'AccelerometerNoise', 0.002, ...
           'LinearAccelerationNoise', 0.003, ...
           'GyroscopeNoise', 0.444, 'GyroscopeDriftNoise', 0.445);
% when 10 samples come in, call below function

function [orientation] = runtime_get_orientation(accelerometer, gyro, FUSE)
    [orientation,~] = FUSE(accelerometer, gyro);
end
```

I'd like to return the object state of the FUSE object back to the calling function, so that I can pass it as an argument back in. I expect that this is some sort of a matrix object. I want to do that because I will eventually want to export it as a c++ function, and exporting a FUSE object might not be possible from what I can tell.

What can I do to keep the state of the FUSE object, in a way that is codegen / c++ friendly?

Comment: @CrisLuengo ah, gosh. Chris, that was it. I completely forgot about them. If you place that as the answer below, I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to make the data a static variable in the function. That way, you can create the filter only the first time the function is called, and you don’t need to know about it outside of the function.

To declare a static variable in MATLAB, use the [`persistent`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) keyword.